# Limiting Poisson Process

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, poisson-process

I'm struggling with the following problem: Suppose there are $n$ bins and balls arrive as a Poisson Process with rate 1. On arrival each ball falls into a bin uniformly likely. Let $M_n$ be the maximum number of balls in any bin at time $n$. Show that

$$P\left(M_n\ge(1+\epsilon)\frac{\log{n}}{\log \log{n}}\right) \to0$$
with $n$.

And we are given the 'hint' that if $X$ a Poisson Process with rate $1$, then
$$P(X\ge x)\le \exp(x-x\log{x})$$

My idea was to use the fact that since #balls in each bin is independent; $P(M_n<k) = P($all bins have $\le k$ members) = $P$(bin 1 has $\le k$ members)$^n$. And as arrivals to bin $1$ are Poisson with rate $1/n$, this is equal to $$\left(e^{-1}(1+1+1/{2!}+...+1/{n!})\right)^n$$ which we want to show converges to $1$. But this is really turning the problem into an analysis question rather than a probability question which is not what I want to do. Also it doesn't use the hint.

Comment: The hint should be rephrased as: "If $X$ is a Poisson random variable (not a Poisson process) with parameter $1$ then $P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant u(x)$ with $u(x)=\exp(x-\log x)$". Now, your remark is that the number of balls in each bin is a Poisson random variable with parameter $1$. This is the way to go, since this yields $P(M_n<k)=P(X<k)^n$, hence $P(M_n<k)\geqslant(1-u(k))^n$. Now the task is to show that, for $k_n=(1+\epsilon)\log n/\log\log n$, $u(k_n)\ll1/n$, right? Can you do that?

Comment: @Did Is the hint supposed to be 
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant \exp(x-\log x)
$$
as you wrote, or
$$
\mathbb P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant \exp(x-x\log x)
$$
as is stated in the question?

Comment: I changed it :)

Comment: @Math1000 The hint as it was previously written was radically unsuited to get any upper bound of the desired quantity. Mind you, I had not even noticed the mistake in the question... :-)